# Blackberry service and ui application running

Tags: blackberry

My code is -

```
 if ( args != null && args.length > 0 && args[0].equals("background1") ){
        // Keep this instance around for rendering
        // Notification dialogs.
         // Start a new app instance for GUI operations.     
        BackgroundApplication backApp=new BackgroundApplication();
        backApp.setupBackgroundApplication();   
       // backApp.enterEventDispatcher();
} 
    else {       
         theApp = new EntryPointForApplication();
         theApp.enterEventDispatcher();    

   }
```

I want to run a background service (in auto start up) and an ui application. When i click the application background1, then its working. The background service is not running. I want to run the background service. How to run this ?. I am getting the error-

Detail formatter error:  java.util.Arrays cannot be resolved to a type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using Alternate entry point in your application ...

After creating the project for the original application, create an alternate entry point to launch the application UI.

- Double click on BlackBerry_App_Descriptor.xml within your project.
- Check off System Module and Do not display the application icon on the BlackBerry home screen.
- Click on the Alternate Entry Point tab.
- Click the Add button.
- Enter a title for the entry point and click OK.
- Specify the application argument that would launch the application using this alternate entry
  point (for example: background1).

**Make a class Wich will extend Application rather than UiApplication 
and check the main method like this ...**

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
     if(args.length>0&&"background1".equals(args[0])){
         //Start your Background Process here 


        }

     else{
        //Start your Gui application here 
     }
}
```

Comment: how to Check off System Module ?

Comment: you can just do like this give the application argument and add alternate entry point thats all

Comment: i implemented this, but its showing the same error-Detail formatter error: java.util.Arrays cannot be resolved to a type .  the Background Process is not starting. how can i find , the background process is working ?.

Comment: Change your main method like in my code ...and see if it works

Comment: is your alaternate entry points name and one you are using in the main method is same check that...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5222/discussion-between-bbdev-and-rez-john)